# Calculating derivative of 2x, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{2(x+h) - 2x}{h}$$

$$=$$

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{2x + 2h - 2x}{h}$$

$$=$$

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{2h}{h}$$

$$=$$

$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}h$$

So the derivative of $2x$ is $0$? But it's actually $2$ right?

I'm sure I'm being really stupid somewhere here.

Comment: Oh god, read your second last and last line. For heaven's sake, while posting this you should have been more careful.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг lol

Comment: $\dfrac{2h} h = 2,\text{ not } h$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2h}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}2=2.$$

Comment: Heh... Yeah, that would be it.Sorry for the dumb post and thanks for answering. I'm still learning these things and algebra doesn't come naturally yet, as you can see =/

Comment: @user123 No need to apologize.  Everybody on this site was at some point exactly where you are in the learning process, and everyone makes mistakes like this every now and then.  Some people seem to forget that and some people perhaps remember but are just less polite about it than others.  Meh.